# Rope/cloth around wood?

Tags: modeling

How do i make rope or cloth tied organically around 2 wooden logs holding them together? I tried shrink wrap on a cylinder (without caps) but it seems really bad.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could create an edge that roughly rotates around the pillars:

[image]

Give it a series of modifiers: *Subdivision Surface (to add vertices between the existing vertices) + Shrinkwrap* (with the pillars as target, play with the *Offset* value) + *Skin* (to give it thickness, enable its *Smooth Shading* option) + *Subdivision Surface*  (to smooth the shape):

[image]

Comment: OKay. I will try this. Although shrinkwrap isn't my best friend but a man's gotta try. Haha.